# Embedding BitBucket Code in Posting

Tags: plugins, posts, shortcode

I want to embed my code at BitBucket in wp post, anyone can suggest me, a good plugin or anytrick to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here try the below code, it should give you a good start.

```
// requrires 3 arguments
// user, project, path
// usage e.g: [bitbucket user="jespern" project="django-piston" path="piston/utils.py"]
function bitbucket_code( $atts ) {
    extract( $atts );
    global $post;
    $path_to_name = str_replace("/", "_", $path);
    $meta_key = "bitbucket_{$user}_{$project}_{$path_to_name}";
    $code = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true );
    if ( !$code ) {
        $bitbucket_url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/$user/$project/raw/tip/$path";
        // just in case its not there ;)
        if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
                include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );
        $request = new WP_Http();
        $response = $request->request( $bitbucket_url );
        $code = htmlentities( $response['body'] );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, $code );
    }
    return '<pre>'. $code . '</pre>';
}               
add_shortcode('bitbucket', 'bitbucket_code');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use of [WP Bucket](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bucket/) for your plugins or themes.

**Create plugin "WB Embed Code" using "WP Bucket" :**

```
<?php 
/*
    Plugin Name: WB Embed Code
    Plugin URI: https://bitbucket.org/khosroblog/wb-embed-code/
    Description: A simple plugin created by the WP Bucket plugin for embed bitbucket codes in the wordpress posts with shortcode.
    Author: Hadi Khosrojerdi
    Version: 0.1.0
    Author URI: http://khosroblog.com
    License: GNU General Public License v2 or later 
*/


    /*
    * Set http arguments.
    * 
    * @since 0.1.0
    * @param array $args An array of http arguments.
    */
    function set_http_args( $http_args ){
        // To avoid error display :
        // WARNING: C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php:1765 - gzinflate(): data error
        $http_args['decompress'] = false;
        return $http_args;
    }
    add_action("wprest_http_request", "set_http_args");


    /*
    * Embed bitbucket code in wordpress posts.
    * 
    * @since 0.1.0
    * @param array $args An array of arguments like repo_slug, class, is_private.
    * @usage e.g : [bitbucket revision="v0.1.2" repo_slug="wp_bucket" owner="khosroblog" path="readme.txt" is_private="0" ]
    * @return html | null .
    */
    function wb_embed_code( $args=array() ){
        global $authordata, $WP_Bucket;
        if( !is_a( $WP_Bucket, "WP_Bucket") ){ return; }

        $defaults = array(
            "repo_slug"     =>  "", // repository slug
            "owner"         =>  "", // username
            "revision"      =>  "master", //A SHA1 value for commit. also you can determine a branch , bookmark or tag name for that.
            "path"          =>  "", // a file or directory exists in the repository
            "is_private"    =>  0
        );

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
        extract( $args );

        $author_id = (int) $authordata->ID;
        // for public reposities you don't need to user authenticate, so tokens should be null.
        if( !$is_private ){
            $WP_Bucket->config(array(
                "oauth_token"        => null,
                "oauth_token_secret" => null,
            ));

        // for private repositories author should be authenticate. 
        // so click on the "login by bitbucket" button in the "wp-bucket-test" page. ( http://yoursite/wp-bucket-test ) 
        }else{
            $WP_Bucket->config( "wp_user_id=" . $author_id );
        }

        $repository = $WP_Bucket->api("/1.0/repositories/$owner/$repo_slug/raw/$revision/$path");
        if( !is_wp_error( $repository ) ){
            echo "<pre>" . esc_html( $repository ) . "</pre>" ;
        }else{
            //var_dump( $repository  );
        }
    }
    add_shortcode("bitbucket", "wb_embed_code");

?>
```

You can to download plugin "WB Embed Code" from the following link:

https://bitbucket.org/khosroblog/wb-embed-code/wiki/Home